# CopyFile isn't copying my file with the same extension?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make it so my user can copy files from one folder to another folder, their playlist folder, so that they can use it throughout my program. So I tried this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to finish the playlist?", "Finish Playlist- WikiFinder", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If (result = DialogResult.Yes) Then
        For Each Item In ListBox1.Items
            Dim str As String = IO.Path.Combine(MusicMenu.FolderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath, "DONUTS")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Item.ToString(), str)
        Next
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

This works and makes the file, but the issue is I told it to copy an MP3 file and it just gave me a "File". Is there any way I can copy the file AND keep the original file's extension?

Comment: Use Path.GetExtension(fileName) to get the file extension and append it to the filename string.

Comment: Do I append it by saying "filename.extension"?

Comment: Where are the original files? I only saw the destination "filenames" came from ListBox1.Items. No extension info source shown in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass only the directory to the *CopyFile* function, it creates a FILE.
Pass filename with Extension.

```
For Each Item In ListBox1.Items
   Dim str As String = IO.Path.Combine(MusicMenu.FolderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath, "DONUTS")
   str = IO.Path.Combine(str,IO.Path.GetFileName(Item.ToString()))
   My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Item.ToString(), str)
Next
```

Now the files will be copied to your DONUTS folder.